# Play! scala and Akka: how to test if an actor A sent a message to an actor B?

Tags: scala, testing, playframework, akka, actor

I want to test that an actor A send a message to an actor B after have received a message.

I'm using Play! 2.5 and I use the factories since I need to inject some of my classes and things like wSClient inside the actors.

The Actor A looks like:

```
object ActorA {
  trait Factory {
    def apply(ec: ExecutionContext, actorBRef: ActorRef): Actor
  }
}

class ActorA @Inject()(implicit val ec: ExecutionContext,
                       @Named("actor-b") actorBRef: ActorRef)
    extends Actor with ActorLogging with InjectedActorSupport {

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case i: Long =>
      log info s"received $i"
      actorBRef ! (i+1)
}
```

And the actor B is even more simple:

```
object ActorB {
  trait Factory {
    def apply(): Actor
  }
}

class ActorB extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case _ =>
      log error "B received an unhandled message"
  }
}
```

But my test doesn't pass, it is said that the expected message doesn't arrive, I get a Timeout in the test (but it is well logged by the actor B) so the problem comes from the test (and probably the Probe).

Here is the test:

```
  val actorBProbe = TestProbe()
  lazy val appBuilder = new GuiceApplicationBuilder().in(Mode.Test)
  lazy val injector = appBuilder.injector()
  lazy val factory = injector.instanceOf[ActorA.Factory]
  lazy val ec = scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
  lazy val factoryProps = Props(factory(ec, actorBProbe.ref))
  val ActorARef = TestActorRef[ActorA](factoryProps)

  "Actor B" must {

    "received a message from actor A" in {
      ActorARef ! 5L

      actorBProbe.expectMsg(6L)
    }
  }
```

I also created a minimum Play! application with the code above available [here](https://github.com/ticketapp/play-testing-actors).

Comment: Note that there is a method `unhandled` that you can override to catch all unhandled messages. Also, if you only want to test whether one actor forwards a message to another actor, I would leave out the play framework things and bootstram everything manually to simplify the scenario and possible side-effects.

Comment: I don't fiind the related doc in order to use the method unhandled, could you please point it to me? For the rest of your comment, I don't only want to know if an actor forwards a message. I using it inside a Play! app and my use case is really more complicated but I simplify for the purpose of the question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your test, `actorBProbe` is not the ActorB ref passed to ActorA constructor (of ref `ActorARef`).  What really happens is that Guice creates a different ActorB (named `actor-b`), and passes its ref to ActorA (of ref `ActorARef`) constructor.

The test ends up with ActorB `actor-b` receiving `6L` (as evident in log). While `actorBProbe` receives nothing.

The confusion really comes from mixing Guice lifecyle with Actors.  In my experience, it creates more pains than I can bear.

To prove, simply print hash code of ActorRef's, you'll see they are different. Illustrated as followings:

```
val actorBProbe = TestProbe()
println("actorBProbe with ref hash: " + actorBProbe.ref.hashCode())
```

And,

```
class ActorA ... {
  override def preStart =
    log error "preStart actorBRef: " + actorBRef.hashCode()

  // ...
}
```

In fact, even `ec` inside ActorA is not the same `ec` in the test code.

The following is a way to "force" the test to pass and at the same time prove that `actorBProbe` wasn't really being used by ActorB.

In stead of relying on Guice to "wire in" ActorB, we tell Guice to leave it alone by replacing `@Named("actor-b")` with `@Assisted`, like this,

```
import ...
import com.google.inject.assistedinject.Assisted

class ActorA @Inject()(...
  /*@Named("actor-b")*/ @Assisted actorBRef: ActorRef)
...
```

Re-run the test, it'll pass. But this is probably not what you wanted to begin with.